# Can i use dispatch like setState in this problem?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was converting this app to Redux but the custom handle function is using {name , value } = event.target

```
  handleChange = event => {      
      const { name, value } = event.target;

      this.setState({
          [name] : value
      });
  }
```

here they are taking single handler for all fields dynamically
but in my case istead of setState i used dispatch 'react-redux hooks'

```
     this.setState({
          [name] : value
      });

     dispatch(reducerName({
          type: 'SET_NAME / SET_EMAIL / SET_any_other_fiels',
          payload: value
      })
```

the solution i have is to make handleChange[type] for every fields
or i can do some thing else ?
i have field for

```
let initialState = {
   name,
   email,
   walletid:'',
    payout:0,
    bank:{          
      bank: 0,
      expenditures: 0,
      fees: 0,
      income: 0,
      receipts: 0,
      rejected: 0          
    }
}
i want to share the single case in reducer to add all fields
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass directly key, value in action payload and use them in the reducer.

```
 var payload = {
           name: name,
           value: value
          }

 dispatch(reducerName({
              type: 'SETFIELDS',
              payload: payload
          })

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type == 'SETFIELDS') {
            // Return new modified state
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
            };
        }
        // Default
        return state;
}
```

Comment: i look great thanks , but i my case i am using the reducer for other fields too to set other data. can i use switch along with if or i have to use if-else-ladder

Comment: you can go with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want onChange to modify global store values?

Anyway, if this is what you wish for - how about this:

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type.startsWith('SET')) {
            // Get all parts expect SET part (for example ['ANY', 'OTHER', 'FIELD'])
            const actionKeyArr = action.type.split('_').slice(1);
            // Make it one long string, as saved on initial state (for example 'anyotherfield')
            const keyToChange = actionKeyArr.join('').toLowerCase();

            // Return new modified state
            return {
                ...state,
                [keyToChange]: action.payload
            };
        }

        // Default
        return state;
}
```

Comment: so in this case i'm using switch for other purpose like `switch( action.type ) {
        case 'SET_DATA':
            return state.data = action.payload` can i use both along if